# How to go back to last commit + delete all newly created files?

Tags: git

As in the title: "How to go back to last commit + delete all newly created file?" Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to undo the last Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you've done a bunch of work, haven't committed it, and want to git rid of that work and go back to your last commit.  Is that correct?  If so, I think you need a combination of two commands:

```
git reset --hard   # reverts tracked files to commit you were working from
git clean -f       # removes untracked files that haven't been added to git yet
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

git reset --hard HEAD^1

This will wipe off your working directory files.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard <commidId>
```

then

```
git clean -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reset` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/2128691)

you can see the full documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)